# indent entire item block in enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, indentation

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}   
\newenvironment{tight_enumerate}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{-1.5em}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}

\subsubsection*{Minimum Working Example}
\begin{tight_enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{tight_enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which gives me the following:

[image]

As you can see, I have tried to indent(move to the left each item). However, only the first line of the item gets indented, while the remaining lines stay in place. I am wondering how to move the entire block in the item to the left.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with the innards of LaTeX's list-like environments can be, to put it politely, a baffling experience. Therefore, rather than keep fiddling with the low-level parameters of a `list` environment directly, I'd recommend you employ the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and use its `left=0pt` and `noitemsep` options.

If this "look" is needed for just one enumerated list, you could provide these options as optional arguments to `\begin{enumerate}`. If it's needed several times, you could use the machinery of the `enumitem` package -- specifically, its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros -- to create a new, bespoke enumerate-like environment that executes these options automatically. Both possibilies are explored in the following MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % filler text
\usepackage{showframe}  % draw rectangle around textblock
\usepackage{enumitem}   % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{tightenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tightenum]{label=\arabic*., left=0pt, noitemsep}

\begin{document}   

\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt, noitemsep]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\hrule  % draw a full-width horizontal line
\begin{tightenum}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{tightenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this detailed explanation!